# When hovering over a div, how do I loop through the rows and display another div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I'm currently trying to show one div when another one is hovered however I am struggling to combine this with a loop.

My HTML is:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="half">
            <img class="restaurant-logo" src=""/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
            <strong><a href="">Continue Reading</a></strong>
            <a class="button order" href="#">Order now</a>
        </div>

        <div class="half image" style="background-image: url();">
            <div class="quote">
                <div class="quote-text"><p>Highlighted text </p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="half">
            <img class="restaurant-logo" src=""/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
            <strong><a href="">Continue Reading</a></strong>
            <a class="button order" href="#">Order now</a>
        </div>

        <div class="half image" style="background-image: url();">
            <div class="quote">
                <div class="quote-text"><p>Highlighted text</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is this:

When you hover over the "order now" button, the .quote-text in the same row changes from opacity 0 to opacity 1.

I've tried to implement an each statement and have also tried to go up to the parent element and back down to another child but for some reason everytime I hover, all of the .quote-text are changing.

My jQuery is below.

```
$('.order').each( function() {
    $(this).hover(
        function() {
            $('.order').closest('.row').find('.quote').css('opacity', '1');
        },
        function() {
            $('.order').closest('.row').find('.quote').css('opacity', '0');
        }
    );
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I feel I am close but my jQuery skills are limited and internet searches and trial and error haven't helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are selecting all the `.order` elements on hover. Instead you can use the `this` keyword to reference only the one which raised the event. Try this:

```
$('.order').each( function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.quote').css('opacity', '1');
    }, function() {
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.quote').css('opacity', '0');
    });
});
```

From there you can make the logic much more succinct by removing the redundant `each()` loop, and providing a single function to `hover()` which is fired under both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event that just calls `toggle()` on the appropriate `.quote`:

```
$('.order').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.quote').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was close! Thank you so much!